# How Can You Clear a Quad Tree Without Recursion ( using queue maybe? )

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, queue, quadtree

Ok given a class along the lines of

```
class quadTree {
 short level;
 Vec2f midpoint;
 quadTree * nodes[4] = { NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};

public:

void newPartition() {
 float j = fWIDTH  / 2 ^ level;
 float k = fHEIGHT / 2 ^ level;
  nodes[0] = new quadTree(level+1, midpoint[0] - j, midpoint[0] + k);
  nodes[1] = new quadTree(level+1, midpoint[0] + j, midpoint[0] + k);
  nodes[2] = new quadTree(level+1, midpoint[0] - j, midpoint[0] - k);
  nodes[3] = new qaudTree(level+1, midpoint[0] + j, midpoint[0] - k);
 }
}
```

How could I implement a function that deletes all the nodes under the current node of the quad tree without recursion probably using a queue? As in a Clear() function.

I'm sorry for asking, I feel like I should know this and just can't quite figure it out. I looked online but couldn't find anything. Any Ideas?

For any example code using a queue just use std::queue.

EDIT :: 
Ok I think this is what I am going to use for reference. I think this should work, correct me if I am wrong.

```
#include <queue>
void helpClear( bool notPassing, queue<quadTree> &q ) {
int count;
for ( int i; i < 4; i++ ) {
 if ( node[i] != NULL){
  q.push ( node[i] );
  count++;
 }
}
quadTree * Point;
if ( notPassing ){
 for ( int i; i < count; i++ ){  
  Point = q.front();
  q.pop();
  Point -> helpClear(0, q);   
}
 for ( int i; i < 4; i ++ )
   delete nodes[i]; 
}
}

void clear () {
  queue <quadTree> q;
  quadTree * Point;
  helpClear(1,q);
  while (!queue.empty() ) {
    quadTree * Point;
    Point = q.front();
    q.pop();
    Point -> helpClear(1,q);
    delete Point;
  }
for ( int i; i < 4; i++ )
    nodes[i] = NULL;
}
```

helpClear() is a private function of quadTree and clear() is the public function you call to delete all nodes below the current node.

Comment: Whilst avoiding recursion is generally not a bad idea, I'm pretty certain this is a good case of "but avoiding recursion is not ALWAYS a good idea." - in this case, recursion will be MUCH easier than stacking up the objects to delete into a queue and then deleting the queue.

Comment: I am dealing with massive quad trees and a large amount of data that may be putting different stresses on the stack. I'm talking the size that if i just recursively invoke their deconstructors I could cause a seg fault. Do you know how I might do it?

Comment: That seems strange, as the whole point of a quadtree is that there aren't that many levels, making for a fairly shallow recursion.

Comment: `Point = q.front(); q.pop();` can be just `Point = q.pop();`. And the generally preferred way of doing this would be sticking it in the destructor (which is still recursive, but this is unlikely to be a problem - a depth of 10000 should be no problem for recursion, which means, for a somewhat balanced tree, more nodes than can possibly **ever** fit into memory (my calculation indicates `5*10^3624` nodes)). And class names general start with a capital letter - `QuadTree`.

Comment: You are making the assumption that the only thing on the stack of this program is a quad tree which isn't the case. Also you cant replace     Point = q.front(); q.pop(); with just Point = q.pop();

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/pop/

not with std::queue. And yeah I know they do, but I always end up giving them lower case first words then uppercase following words. Its a habit.

Comment: Please do not edit (answered) or (alternate methods welcome) into your title; that's not what the title is for.

Comment: @PhobicHD - Are you shooting for quickly deleting the structure or low memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ideas (approaches):

1) If you can control all `newPartition()`-actions at the one point (for instance, at the top level), you can implement special buffer of `quadTree` pointers and collect in it all nodes (any of `std` `list`, `vector`, `queue`, ...).

In this case, when you need to clean up all nodes, you can just clean up all child-nodes by pointers in this buffer without using a stack.

2) If your QuadTree uses strict order of nodes (in spatial sense), you can organize all of your pointers in one container. For example:

Level 0 (1 pointer):

```
1111
1111
1111
1111
```

Level 1 (4 pointers)

```
2233
2233
4455
4455
```

Level 2 (16 pointers)

```
ABEF
CDGH
IJMN
KLOP
```

In container order will be like this:

```
12345ABCDEFGHIJKLOP
```

Relationships between levels can be resolved by math calculations, due to every level needs precisely 2^N elements.

This solution doesn't need extra pointers (and 0 pointers at all), and solve your stack problem. However, it needs more time to move from parent to child and from child to parent, and can consume more memory if your levels in QuadTree are different (by number of elements in one of, for instance less than 2^N).

Note: it's a very rare type of solution and in the most cases recursive is better.

Comment: Another good solution but I would like to be able to do it as lightly on memory as possible. Thank you, I actually did consider this and will probably resort to it if I give up.

Comment: Ok that is a lot more clear, thank you. I thought you meant to have a double reference one in the quad tree and another in this table.

Comment: this is a morton index, also called z-order index, see my answer. databases use that trick.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications can use a quadtree that is transformed to an array with key "morton Index". Such a quad tree is an huge array, without any child pointers.
You can delete this as simple as deleting an array.

However not all applications can use that MortonIndexed Quadtree.

But recursion should be no problem, because the quadtree should not have a depth of more than 16. If much deeper then you are using the wrong type of quad tree.

Answer (score -1):

I use my custom tree implementation to avoid recursion. In my realization Node contains pointer to Parent Node, Child Node and Next Plain(one level depth) node. Using this data it's easy to implement non recursive tree iteration.

Comment: That is a viable solution but at that point why aren't I just allocating a huge queue from the heap and pushing every node to the queue? This would probably be more efficient than keeping up to 17 extra node pointers per node ( if i understand what you mean by next plain ). Still I could reduce that to a single node to the parent and use something I already wrote.  This is all memory intensive however and I haven't memory to spare, that the problem.